# PointGrey ladybug fails to open on linux

Tags: camera, linux-device-driver

I use ladybug driver of the github project called `CPFL/Autoware` on ubuntu 16.04 for Ladybug 5 of PointGrey. when I capture images for a moment, the driver fails and the error message shows ***isoch operation failed***. The problem usually happens after capturing images for 30 mins normally.

Comment: No one has responds for this problem. Exactly I have met the problem hardly people met. I think maybe there are some problems with Autoware driver of Ladybug.